# Stratified Random Sampling of Ratio (X/Y) where X itself is an estimate

Tags: standard-error, sampling

I am trying work out the variance of the population estimate var (R) where R = X/Y (X = sum(x) and Y = sum(y)).  For each member of the population I know y and I have stratified the population and taken a random sample of each strata.  For each member of the sample I need to estimate x.  x is not known with certainty and the estimate of x has its own standard error (which I can estimate from a pre sample calibration exercise).  However, which I know enough to know that this error should be taken into account my knowledge of sample statistics is limited to the situation where x is a quantity that can be exactly determined.

If anyone can help with an answer or point me to anappropriate reference source it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to translate what you said into math and answer your question. If my translation into math is not correct please clarify via the comments and I will edit my response as appropriate.

You have:

$R = \frac{\sum_i{X_i}}{\sum_i{Y_i}}$

where,

$i= 1, 2, ..n$ index members of the population,

$Y_i$ is a constant

$X_i$ is a random variable with an estimated $Var(X_i)$ (this is what you call as the standard error).

Thus,

$Var(R) = \frac{ n Var(X_i) }{(\sum_i{Y_i})^2}$